# Fatal error after quote submission

Tags: magento-1.8, error

I'm using the Cart2Quote quotation extension for my webshop. Since a day or 2 we have been receiving errors once a new quote is submitted. Clients submitting a quotation get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /home/hotelsup/domains/hotel-supply.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php on line 755

Magento is currently running on 1.8.0, and has been running for 3 weeks now with not errors at all. No additional extensions have been installed or any changes made to the system (upgrade etc).

I've contacted C2Q and they told me that this is a Magento error and has nothing to do with the extension. Can someone enlighten me a bit on this error and how I could solve this problem?

Also the quotation is visible in the backend as being submitted, however, when opened the same error is displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the error appear on the standard checkout? If the error appears only when certain products are added to the cart try the standard checkout with those products.

Comment: No the placement of orders all goes without any problems. Quotation gives errors no matter which products are added.

Comment: At the line specified in the error message there is something related to the product custom options. Most probably, this line of code returns null `$this->getProduct($product)->getCustomOption(self::OPTION_PREFIX . $optionId)`. I know it's not much, but it's a place to start

Comment: That is right Marius. For this reason you would expect the error to show when a product with custom options was added to the quotation. However, products without any options encounter the same problem.

Comment: If you want to try alternative of cart2quote extension, checkout https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated the problem further and I got it all working again. Apparently if your working with a combination of the Mageworx Advanced Product Options and Cart2Quote extensions this might happen. Best thing to do is empty your Cache folder (var/cache) and probably everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

Update code in MageWorx Extension observer.php file

```
$post=$quoteItem->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')->getValue();

Replace above line with following code 

$customObject = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest');
if($customObject)
{
        $post = $customObject->getValue();

}
```